# How to show all users which are in sum have 50 percents in spark scala (sql)?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Lets say I have data - clicks (1) means what users clicked on the displayed advertising

```
Users | clicks
  A   |   1 
  A   |   1 
  B   |   0
  B   |   0
  C   |   1 
  C   |   0
  D   |   1
  D   |   0
  E   |   0
  E   |   0
```

I need to bring out all the people who in total clicked on 50% of the displayed ads

In our case, total clicks - 4 times, and I need follow output

```
Users | clicks | percents
  A   |   2    |    50
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, sum up the number of clicks. Then calculate the percentage and finally filter for all rows larger than 50%:

```scala
val df = Seq(("A", 1), ("A", 1), ("B", 0), ("B", 0), ("C", 1), ("C", 0),
        ("D", 1), ("D", 0), ("E", 0), ("E", 0))
    .toDF("Users", "clicks")
val allĆlicks = df.filter("Clicks > 0").count
df.groupBy("Users").sum()
  .withColumn("percents", $"sum(clicks)"/allĆlicks*100)
  .filter("percents >= 50")
  .show()
```

prints:

```
+-----+-----------+--------+
|Users|sum(clicks)|percents|
+-----+-----------+--------+
|    A|          2|    50.0|
+-----+-----------+--------+
```